# Having SO Careers in the drop down for the CrossValidated site?

Tags: feature-request, jobs, top-bar

I have noticed the SO Careers tab in the drop down list of sites like ServerFault, etc.

> [image]

As SO careers also have data scientists and analysts careers in them, would it be sensible if it is included for CrossValidated too?

---

[Corresponding discussion](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2738/having-a-so-careers-in-the-drop-down) on the CrossValidated Meta site, which [vouches](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2738/having-a-so-careers-in-the-drop-down/2755#2755) for the site's interest.